# 2sxc How to debug a query

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have created a view for a "details" page, and have set up a visual query to get the required item from a query string variable.

Testing the query works, and a single item is returned in the test:

```
{
  "Default": [
    {
      "Title": "The Person",
      "JobTitle": "CEO",
      "Organization": "The Company",

       etc (exactly what is expected)

    }
  ]
}
```

This is piped to the Default input of the 2sxc Target, and running the test shows that 1 item is sent to the Target.

Now, when I actually execute the module, what I get is "No demo item exists for the selected template." which indicates that the data is not actually getting to the module.

I have selected the query as the data source for the view.

How to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a different problem: your view has a content-type defined, but no demo-item. In this scenario, it shows the message you see. So either say "no content-type" or give it a demo-item. Then the template is run.